# HtmlAgilityPack Segment content at specific tag(s)

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

So let's say I have a html document the looks something Like this:

```
<h1>Segment1</h1>
<p>Segment1Text</p>
<p>Segment1MoreText</p>
<ul><li>Segment1BulletText</li></ul>
<h1>Segment2</h1>
<p>Segment2Text</p>
<p>Segment2MoreText</p>
<ul><li>Segment2BulletText</li></ul> 
<h1>Segment3</h1>
<p>Segment3Text</p>
<p>Segment3MoreText</p>
<ul><li>Segment3BulletText</li></ul>
```

Using HTMLAgilityPack I need to create a function that will segment my html into HTMLNodeCollections based the split pattern I pass in to this function.

- So I could have 1 pattern where I say to split at each h1 tag (return 3 html node collections).
- I could have another split pattern that says split at h1 tag followed by a p tag (return 3 html node collections)..
- Another pattern that says split when we have an h1 tag followed by a p tag, followed by another p tag (return 3 html node collections). etc...

This function would need to be extensible because the html segments that I pass in are always going to be different and therefore I will always need to provide it with different patterns in order to segment the html.

Comment: what you have tried so far. is not a good way to ask  the question

Comment: when you say it should 3 collections, you mean 3 collections containing what?

Answer (score 0):

`.Descendants()` is your friend here (if you don't want to use XPATH).

For your 1st question: just use `Descendants("h1")`.

2nd question: Something like this would work `doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("h1").Where(p => p.NextSibling.NextSibling.Name === "p");` // I did a trick here, because there is always a text node in between. This might not the nicest solution, just to demonstrate idea.

3rd question: Same with 2nd, just get 1 more `NextSibling()`.